# Bootstrap carousel slider not auto start in wordpress...?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've issue with my carousel, which is in bootstrap 2 + wordpress.
I want auto start when page load, but its not work.
when I click on next/prev controller it will and after that auto start work, so that mean on first page load auto start not working.

any one have any idea..?

I've also try with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 500
    }); 
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle');
});
```

---

```
 jQuery('#myCarousel').carousel({
     interval: 2000
 })
```

... but still it doesn't work.....

let me know if anyone have solutions for this..

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firebug to see what errors you get? 
Did you import the JQuery and Bootstrap libraries? Also, your call to the carousel method must be within the  tags.
Try booting it without the fancy options first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(); 

});
</script>
```